# Lambdaj: Loop through Map and get the values and put in other Map

Tags: java, lambda, lambdaj

I'm new to lambdaj so trying to get more used to it. I want to update this code using lambdaj:

```
 Passed in parameter Map<String, Device> devices;
 final Map<String, String> resultHash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Device device : devices.values()) {
            result.put(device.getAddress(), device.getName());
        }
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. index the devices based on their address, will give you a LambdaMap.
2. transform the Device values of the LamdbaMap to their names, giving you a LambdaMap.

From the top of my mind:

```
LambdaCollections.with(devices.values())
    .index(Lambda.on(Device.class).getAddress())
    .convertValues(Lambda.on(Device.class).getName());
```